# What is the best way to stream and store fast changing financial data?

Tags: redis, architecture, microservices

Let's say we have an **Exchange** microservice, that can process exchange between a number of currencies or even digital currencies. For example the user has USD and wants EUR instead.

Few requirements:

1. If all of the instances of this service read the current rate for the same currency at the same time, the result should be the same
2. The rate is changing every 5s

This service needs to get the rates from somewhere, for example a third party provider, and the store it. Since it is real time data, how can we make sure that all the instances of the **Exchange** service get the exact same rate when reading a rate at the same time?

I was thinking in streaming this data from the provider through Kafka topics, and then into a Redis cache, that the microservice instances can use to read. Does it scale well for very high load?

Answer (score 0):

Every 5s is very low load for Redis. A single Redis instance can easily do 10s of thousands operations per sec.

Assuming you keep a single key per currencies rate then you can even easily scale it with Redis Cluster in case you see it doesn't hold.